# How to start aufs for two local directories

Tags: debian, sandbox, aufs

I'm trying to create a sandbox for testing an untrusted software. I'm using Debian, I have installed `aufs-tools`.

When I try to mount a minimal example with the following command:

```
mount -t aufs -o dirs=./write=rw:/=ro none ./mount
```

I'm getting:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on none,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
       need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

Using `br:` instead of `dirs=` gives the same.